# How long does it generally take Apple to propagate subject category changes in my submitted eBooks

Tags: itunes, books, itunes-producer

I have several books on sale in the ibooks store. A couple of weeks ago I did a minor change to the subject category of all my books. About a week after that I started to notice a drop on sales. I am trying to figure out whether this drop might be due to normal seasonal cycles or it might be that my change got propagated and classified the books in the wrong pile.

Comment: I have no idea, but if you moved it from 'shades of grey' to 'angling' that may have an effect too ;)

Comment: See the end of the FAQ for ways to contact Apple about such stuff  http://www.apple.com/itunes/working-itunes/sell-content/books/book-faq.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not seen this change take longer than 48 hours unless there were a long holiday weekend or some shutdown like is typical and emailed/posted months in advance (like December 25 shutdown the last few years past).

If you have a concern, you could always log into iTunes Connect and contact support to check that things are not stuck in your case.

Comment: Thanks @bmike for sharing your experience. I marked this answer as correct because this is what I also experienced after creating a few changes.